# Load image from gallery ionic2 angular 2

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using ionic2 and angular2 to develop mobile app.

In a page, user has to load image from gallery/camera.

Loading image from camera is working fine. But loading image from gallery is not working. It also leads to camera.

**this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY** also leads to camera.

My code is as follows:

```
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';
import { SpeechRecognition } from '@ionic-native/speech-recognition';
..
..
..

 takePicture(type) {
 this.showActionSheet(type);
  }

  public showActionSheet(type) {
   let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
    title: 'Choose the source type',
    buttons: [{
     icon: 'camera',
     text: 'Camera',
     handler: () => {
      this.loadImage(this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, type);
     }
    }, {
     icon: 'image',
     text: 'Gallery',
     handler: () => {
      this.loadImage(this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY, type);
     }
    }, {
     text: 'Cancel',
     role: 'cancel'
    }]
   });
   actionSheet.present();
  }

  private loadImage(selectedSourceType: number, type) {
   let cameraOptions: CameraOptions = {
    sourceType: selectedSourceType,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    quality: 100,
    allowEdit : true,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    correctOrientation: true,
   }
   this.camera.getPicture({
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
   }).then((imageData) => {
    if (type === 'single') {
     this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    } else {
     this.image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
     this.imageList.push(this.image);
    }
   }, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
   });
  }
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Also, mic in android works fine without any issue. But for ios, mic is not working ass expected. Is there any modifications i have to do?

```
listenForSpeech(): void {
  this.isSpeechSupported();
  this.getPermission();
  this.hasPermission();
  this.getSupportedLanguages();

  this.iosOptions = {
   language: 'en-US'
  }

  if (this.platform.is('android')) {
   this.speech.startListening().subscribe(data => this.ivr(data), error =>                                
  console.log(error));
  } else if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
  this.speech.startListening().subscribe(data => this.speechList = data[0], 
 error => console.log(error));
 }
 }
```